# @InstallIn-annotated classes must also be annotated with @Module or @EntryPoint error

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I don't know why I am receiving " @InstallIn-annotated classes must also be annotated with @Module or @EntryPoint: com.example.newsapp.di.AppModule
[Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details." error. I used the tutorial to write this code and the tutor's code (exactly the same as mine) works correctly.
`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
  @Provides
    fun baseURL() = BASE_URL

    @Provides
    fun logging() = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    @Provides
    fun okHttpClient() = okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(logging())
        .build()


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(baseUrl: String): NewsService =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient())
            .build()
            .create(NewsService::class.java)}`
```

Answer (score 7):

I checked imports and found that I imported Module from the wrong place.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Same issue

for annotation:

> @Module

instead of the currect import:

> import dagger.Module

Wrong import:

> import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Myodule

or anything else